# Почему в переменную mass_len_all_world[N] в цикле не правильно записывается значения

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define N 100000
int main() {
int wd = 0, ws = 0,kol_enter=0,kol_strok=0,o=0;
char word[] = { 'o','i','l' }, words[N],matr_words[N][3]; int n = 0;
    scanf("%[^' ']s", &words); while (getchar() != ' '); printf("\n");
    wd = strlen(words);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) { //здесь считается сколько слов||строк в коде
        if (words[i] == '\n') kol_enter++;
        kol_strok = kol_enter + 1;
    }
    int len_all_words = 0, len_all_sym = 0, len_all_wordsS=0, summ_len_all_word = 0, len_last_word = 0, len_all_words_mass,mass_len_all_world[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) {  //считает длину кадлого слова
        for (int s = 0; s < kol_enter; s++) { //для массива mass_len_all_world чтобы заполнялся элементами
            if ((words[i] != '\n') && (words[i] != ' ')) {
                len_all_words++;  
                len_all_wordsS = len_all_words / kol_enter; //дополнителная переменная тк блина слов умножается на количества "\n"
                mass_len_all_world[s] = len_all_wordsS;   //тут собственно иедт заполнение массива
            }
        else {
            if (len_all_words) {
                summ_len_all_word += len_all_words;
                len_all_words_mass = len_all_words + 2;
            }
            len_all_words = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

summ_len_all_word правильно считает какой длины состоит слова, но когда эти данные хочу поместить в массив выдает не правильно
Можете подсказать что я делаю не так?

Comment: Смотря что понимать под "неправильно". Вы просто в цикла записываете в массив одно и то же значение — а почему вы это делаете, это уже вопрос к вам, а не к программе. Она делает то, что вы просите...

Comment: @Harry проблема в том что она записывает в массив последнее значение len_all_words_mass, а первые игнорирует я не понимаю почему тк len_all_words_mass находиться же в цикле и хранит в себе все значения

Comment: Одна переменная типа `int` может хранить *одно* значение. В вашем цикле это значение *не изменяется*, и присваивается всем `kol_enter` значениям массива.

Comment: спасибо
т.е мне надо поменять тип данных массива да?

Comment: Нет, вам надо, *как только вычислили очередную длину*, тут же ее записать в массив. Или вычислять ее сразу в массив, без промежуточных переменных.

Comment: @Harry спасибор! сейчас попробую

Comment: @Harry я изменила код но заполнение идет неправильно можете подсказать почему? 
Что нетак?: к примеру количество строк 5, длина слов 2 4  6 5, а в массив записывается как 2 2 2 5
(размер последнего слова считается отдельно, в массиве его не учитывают)